# Paste address into relevant contact fields

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, input-fields, intuitive

I'm looking for an intuitive UI interaction that allows both:

1. entering contact information as the following fields:

   - First Name
   - Last Name
   - E-Mail Address
   - Phone Number
2. pasting multiple or all of those fields at once, then filling any remaining manually.

Maybe it's just a button that pops up a text box to paste into, but I'm looking for a better experience than that. Ideally something that visually represents the fact that we are pasting into the existing four fields on the page.

We also plan to parse the pasted information, changing from ALL CAPS to Proper Case, formatting the phone number, etc. It's expected that the paste buffer might have any sort of whitespace-delimited contact information that we'll automatically parse using thoughtful code. Examples include:

```
 "Firstname Lastname"
 "Lastname, Firstname<new line>flastname@company.com<new line>(800)555-1212"
 "flastname@company.com 800-555-1212"
```

Has anyone seen something like this?

The client framework is Angular 2 in the browser, but this interaction is fairly important to us, so we're willing to build it from scratch to run in our environment.

Comment: How is the user copying the various fields of data into the clipboard as delineated content?

Comment: Any whitespace would be accepted. I'll add examples above.

Comment: Have you seen how authorisation and serial number entry mechanisms work in the older, more expensive design software when copy-pasting?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I think you are referring to software activation, but I don't know what UX you are referring to.

Comment: In the old days, we'd buy a product and then authorise it online, and that would give us a massive confirmation serial to enter into the product. The product would (often) display a series of boxes that delineated the content by 4, 5 or 6 characters, breaking it up for manual entry recognition... or you could copy paste the entire string into the first box and it would automatically spread out through the others. That's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I don't think you can query the clipboard before the user uses the past functionality (on most platforms) so you'll be unable to visually indicate how much content from the clipboard there is, and how it's going to be distributed from any given box in your forms.

Comment: Where's the data coming from? It seems odd to have data formatted like that and then only paste it in one entry at a time. Would bulk import of a collection of people be a viable alternative?

Comment: @Graham: The data is typically coming from third-party contact management web applications or even local/personal contact notes. Some may not even offer a simple means to copy all related contact fields as one operation, for example the fields may not be displayed in the same section.

Comment: @Confused: Yes, I'm trying to think of an elegant presentation that would advertise the ability to paste multiple components into one field. I typically avoid "wizard" interactions, but I was thinking a more step-by-step process might take care of this. Alternately some sort of hybrid field interaction that presents a large text area with light underscores for the related fields.

Comment: Do your users need to do this repeatedly? Often?

Comment: 80% of 7000 engaged members will do this a few times a day. The more important part is reducing bad data due to sloth or non-intuitive interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to explicitly tell users they can do this, and provide a visual demonstration of the functionality, because this is extremely uncommon. There is almost nothing like this in this era of completely singular copy/paste thinking.

See Ted Nelson's complaints about this ridiculous reduction in the power of computing. He was, so far as I know, the first to think about and articulate in terms of copy/paste, and how it could be in computing. He became furious that it was reduced to a simplistic notion of a one item clipboard. And rightly so.

In today's era this is considered a rant, but well worth a read if you consider UI and UX to be your thing: http://dougengelbart.org/colloquium/session_09/session_09_nelson.html

Comment: It's a well-thought answer. I'll hold out for a solution, and try to remember to accept this if/when I lose hope.

Comment: Accepting, about a year later. :)